# Active directory HyperV VM to VMware

Tags: active-directory

we just copied an active directory VM from an Hyper-V VM to a VMware one.
This Hyper-v VM is our second active directory server (the first one is a physical server). We used Symantec Backup Exec to restore our VM to VMware. Those 2 VMs are normally almost identical and the HyperV one is still the one in production.

We want now to switch off the Hyper-V VM and power on the VMware one, we intend to :

- switch off the HyperV VM
- switch on the VMware one and modify its IP to take the one from the inactive HyperV VM
- reboot the vmware VM

Is there another thing to check before (i'm sure there are but i did not find it for this use case) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as described provided that

- you have performed a **[non-authoritative restore of the DC from a system state backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816627(v=ws.10).aspx)** on the ESXi version of the DC
- your backup is more recent than the [tombstone lifetime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784932(v=ws.10).aspx) of your forest (default is 180 days for DCs running Server 2003 SP2 or newer and 60 days for previous versions)

The non-authoritative restore part is crucial as otherwise your directory would see a [USN rollback condition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875495/en-us). Just restoring from an image (or reverting to a snapshot) won't do.

I would recommend [watching this video regarding AD operations in virtualized environments](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/SIM406) as the snapshot-revert virtualization scenario is very similar to a simple image restore. VMWare also has a [nice paper](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/solutions/Virtualizing-Active-Directory-Domain-Services-on-VMware-vSphere.pdf) online which is (among others) covering the revert-to-snapshot topic for AD DCs.

In general, it is a safer and simpler approach to switch off the to-be-converted DC, convert the virtual disk to the destination format and switch it on on the new platform. It would incur additional downtime for the duration of the conversion procedure, though.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you i would prefere to power down the Hyper-V VM, and then make a convert of the powered down VM via VMWare Converter Standalone editon. And then only power on the new VMware-VM without powering on the old hyper-V VM anymore.

I would feel more safe this way, but it's up to you.

There are also other tools like StarWind V2V Image converter.

The problem i see: if you used Backup Exec i think you made an online backup, right? I would't do that with a dc. i think you can get many problems with timestamps and synchronisation. But its only a guess...

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone is overthinking this one.

Just install a new server and promote it on the VMware infrastructure. Then transfer any FSMO roles and decomission the old DC.

Comment: But our payroll software runs on this domain controller!!

Comment: you have a virtual environment and didn't made a new VM for the payroll software? Sorry but that isn't a very good concept i think. Can't you separate them? - If the software wasn't installed on DC i think MDMarra is right...